# Exposing Specific endpoints on a port - Vigor 2820n

Tags: firewall, router, vigor

I have a vigor 2820n router I want to allow an external (public) service to call into a specific endpoint that calls an HTTP server, e.g. `http://my.public.ip:8989/open_to_the_world`.

So far so good & I can achieve this will opening port 8989 on the router and mapping to my web server..

However, this gives access to the entire web-server and not just to the endpoint `open_to_the_world`; is there any way just to allow traffic to the `open_to_the_world` endpoint go through and for all other traffic to be refused by router configuration?

Answer (score 1):

On routers/firewalls, you deal with IPs/ports only unless you have a router with special capabilities to deal with URLs. Normally, such a restriction on URLs can be done on the web server like apache and/or a proxy server.

If you need help in configuring your web server, you need first to tell us what are you using.

Comment: Thanks - I"m using Tomcat 7 however I need the internal network (i.e. behind the router) to still have full access - was hoping I could do this on the router so the outside work doesn't hit tomcat at all (unless with the open_to_world endpoint)

Comment: @lan: You can exclude your internal IPs from this restriction. Other IPs will be allowed access to this specific URL.